# how to convert currency to decimal in Azure Data Factory's copy data activity mapping

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory i have a pipe line and pipeline has one copy data activity that has a source a REST api and a destination a SQL DB Table.

In the mapping of this copy activity i am telling that which columns from REST dataset (on left) will be mapped to which columns on SQL dataset (onright)

[image]

there is a json property in Rest "totalBalance" that is supposed to be mapped to "Balance" field in DB Tables.

Json has "totalBalance" as string for example "$36,970,267.07" so how to convert this into decimal so that i can map it to DataBase table?

do i need to some how use mapping activity instead of copy activity ? or just the copy activity can do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally what worked for me was having a copy activity and a mapping activity.

Copy activity copies data from REST to SQLtable where all the columns are VARCHAR type and from that table a mapping activity sinks data from SQL(allString) tables to actual destination SQLTable.

But between mapping and sink i added "Derived Column" for each source property i want to convert and in expression of that derived column i am using expression like this

**toDecimal(replace(replace(totalAccountReceivable, '$', ''),',',''))**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The copy activity can not do that directly.

There are two way I think can do this:

First:change decimal to varchar in DB Tables.

Second:add a lookup activity before copy activity and remove the '$' in 'totalBalance' column,then add an additional column like this:

[image]

Finally,use this additional column map to 'Balance' column.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: what will be a source of lookup activity? because it does not allow REST to be its source.

Comment: so now i have a copy activity that copies from REST to Azure Table. after that i have a lookup activity. after that i have another copy ativity from azure table to sql table. 
in the mapping of second copy activity i added a new column callsed DecimalBalance and gave an expression 

@replace(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].totalAccountReceivable,'$','')

but this just converts the firstRow and copy it in rest of the rows. how can i do it like it picks up value from totalAccountReceivable one by one and keep on removing '$; from it.

Comment: you can use HTTP as your look activity's source.

Comment: so this value[0] issue dont have any fix ?

Comment: and http is like setting up a server. its not about calling REST.

Comment: value[0] issue is hard to solve.Because you will get many rows when you use lookup activity from azure table.Even if you remove '$' of all rows by using foreach activity,it can not use DecimalBalance(additional column) to replace  totalAccountReceivable in your Azure Table. According to your screenshot of your question body,you just want to copy first row of reportData,so I advise you to use lookup activity and additional column.REST is based on HTTP.You can also use HTTP call REST url.