# Alternative to MONEY Data type in Azure data factory

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-mapping-data-flow

From an on-premise PostgreSQL DB I am trying to take it as source in the mapping data flow of Azure data factory. In postgreSQL DB table their is a column with values '$22.44', their(PostgreSQL DB) one can use MONEY datatype. Is their any alternative to MONEY in the Azure data factory. I can use string, But that is an incorrect way to import the data. So please recommend any other alternative if available.

Thank you!

Comment: Use `decimal` or `numeric`. The use of the money type is [discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_money) anyway

Comment: you can reverse as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62921774/how-to-convert-currency-to-decimal-in-azure-data-factorys-copy-data-activity-ma) later

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit data type for money or currency as we have for date and time. You can use either of `int` or `float` or `decimals` or `string` to store the same.

I see you have already opened this ask in [discussion](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure/alternative-of-money-data-type-in-azure-data-factory/m-p/3248489), you can post to support or as an idea [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c) too to get an official response.